# Overwriting Original Values In Collections

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am fetching data from database and storing it on `$groups`. It has different `created_at` for each entry.

I want to overwrite on `created_at` field in collection, just before returning it to the view, and have nice `->diffForHumans()` version.

```
$groupsArray = $messages;

foreach($groupsArray as $key => $group) {

 var_dump($groupsArray[$key]['created_at']); // works: 2015-10-17 21:55:46.000000'

 var_dump($groupsArray[$key]['created_at']->diffForHumans()); // Error: A two digit month could not be found Data missing

 $groupsArray[$key]['created_at'] = $groupsArray[$key]['created_at']->diffForHumans();   // Not Working

}

return $groupsArray->toJson();
```

If I change `groupsArray = $messages->toArray();`, the '// Error' bit of above chunk changes to `Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string`.

Eventually, I need to return it as json as it is ajax request. I want to overwrite on `created_at`, so I can use `group[i]['created_at']` in javascript part in the view, after returning and get Carbon versions.

Comment: use & in foreach to overwrite in foreach!

Comment: what do you mean? can you link a reference or something please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure 'created_at' is in your $dates array in your model.
Like described on http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators
Second, you can iterate and update over a collection by doing the following:

```
$messages->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    $item->difference = $item->created_at->diffForHumans(); // 10 hrs ago
    return $item;
});
$messages->toJson();
```

Comment: This does the trick, and I can get the data as `group[i]['difference']`. Thanks a lot. But one problem here is, it gives me difference value as `10 hours after` instead of `10 hours ago`. Any idea?

Comment: :D Now it makes `10 hours before`. Thanks soo much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

use &you can replace the original value !

```
   foreach($groupsArray as &$key => &$group) {

 var_dump($groupsArray[$key]['created_at']); 

  var_dump($groupsArray[$key]['created_at']->diffForHumans()); 

 $groupsArray[$key]['created_at'] = $groupsArray[$key]       ['created_at']->diffForHumans();   // Not Working

 }
```